# Laravel: Eloquent collection search is not returning results

Tags: php, laravel

In my laravel app I'm transforming a JSON file into a laravel collection then I'm performing. I'm executing the method as a laravel command, I'm echoing the variables so I know for certain it's not missing anything.

I'm getting error:

```
Illuminate\Support\ItemNotFoundException
```

My laravel method:

```
$json = File::get(base_path().'/json/Notifications.json');

$notifications = json_decode($json, true);

$notifications = collect($notifications);

echo count($notifications);
echo $this->time;

$dayOfTheWeek = Carbon::now()->dayOfWeek;
       
$todayNotification = $notifications->where('day','=',$dayOfTheWeek)->firstOrFail();
```

My Notifications.json file

```
[
    { "day":1, "time":1,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody1", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":1, "time":2,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody2", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":1, "time":3,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody3", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":2, "time":1,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody4", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":2, "time":2,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody5", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":2, "time":3,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody6", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":3, "time":1,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody7", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":3, "time":2,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody8", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":3, "time":3,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody9", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":4, "time":1,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody10", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":4, "time":2,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody11", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":4, "time":3,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody12", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":5, "time":1,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody13", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":5, "time":2,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody14", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":5, "time":3,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody15", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":6, "time":1,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody16", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":6, "time":2,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody17", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":6, "time":3,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody17", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":7, "time":1,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody18", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":7, "time":2,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody19", "image" : "default"},
    { "day":7, "time":3,"title":"woo", "body":"notifBody20", "image" : "default"}
]
```

Comment: `dayOfWeek` goes from 0 to 6, not from 1 to 7, so the `where` will fail wen it is `0` (`firstOrFail`). Please, do share what Laravel version you are using, and what is throwing that error (which line)

Answer (score 0):

`dayOfWeek` is 0 to 6. So it will not match your `JSON` data. Instead you can use `dayOfWeekIso` which is indexed to your preference. So change this line and i assume it should work as intended.

```
$dayOfTheWeek = Carbon::now()->dayOfWeekIso;
```

Comment: i think they also need to say what day of the week they are starting their week at